# how does gradle wrapper saves form installing gradle if it uses it's build file?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, gradle

I'n newbie to gradle and I saw this paragraph:

```
The Gradle Wrapper is the preferred way of starting a Gradle build. It consists of a batch script for Windows support and a shell script for support on OS X and Linux. These scripts allow you to run a Gradle build without requiring that Gradle be installed on your system. You can install the wrapper into your project by adding the following lines to the build.gradle
```

but I enabled the gradle warpper in the `build.gradle` that is used only after installing gradle. no?

how do you run once without installing gradle? I run it when adding

`task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}`

to the build.gradle file. No?

Answer (score 0):

Once `gradle wrapper` has been run once (which does require another Gradle installation) or the wrapper files have been copied over from another build, and the wrapper files have been committed to source control, all users can (and should) execute the build via the generated `gradlew(.bat)` script, which will automatically download Gradle on the first invocation. This will ensure that:

- Gradle doesn't have to be installed manually
- Everybody is using the exact same Gradle version, as required by the build
- It's trivial to upgrade everybody to a newer Gradle version (e.g. by editing and committing `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`)

Comment: `has been run once (which does require another Gradle installation)` how do you run once without installing gradle? I run it when adding `task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}` to the build.gradle file. No?

Comment: As I said, this *does* require another Gradle installation, or another Gradle build from which you can copy the `wrapper` directory and `gradlew(.bat)` file. However, this is a one-time operation for one person on the team.